# The product of the Jacobian and its transposed inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, transpose, jacobian

I'm going over the exercise 24.3 [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/HTML/chapter24/section02.html), where the author asks about (what I understand to be) the product of a Jacobian matrix and its transposed inverse, which I think is
$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial s}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial t}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial s}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial t}{\partial y} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} \frac{\partial s}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \frac{\partial s}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} \frac{\partial t}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \frac{\partial t}{\partial y}  \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} \frac{\partial s}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} \frac{\partial s}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} \frac{\partial t}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} \frac{\partial t}{\partial y} \end{pmatrix} $$

I couldn't see how this matrix is in any way significant. However, if the transpose is removed from the second factor, I believe it reduces to the identity.

Has the author made a mistake here by asking to take the transpose? or does this matrix indeed have some significance as is?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the author has made a mistake by taking the transpose:the result of the product he proposes to compute has no reasonable significance, . By the way the course is extremely sloppy with definitions like "A function f of one real variable is said to be differentiable at argument x, if its graph looks like a straight line for arguments in any open interval including x" followed by sarcasic remarks about people who would introduce $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s . My advice: stay far away from these awful notes.

Comment: Yeah I have found Paul's online notes to be far nicer in written content and presentation